# Peer Join Channel error: TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to join channel using kubernetes job.
when I log the particulat job pod, I got

**Error**

> Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0-service:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Then, I log the peer pod and i get the message below:

`TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.18.0.1:43227`

Comment: I believe it is some issue with your crypto material. 
I think the genesis block and channel.tx generated with different crypto material than the crypto material you are using to create the channel.

Comment: @razasikander  how can I verify this?